# How to use mysql instead of mariadb in symfony 5

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, mariadb

i think this might be a stupid question for some, but i swear that i can't find the answer by myself actually.

I'm still learning Symfony so please be nice.

Actually i have set up the access to my database in the .env file :

```
[...]
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:db_password@127.0.0.1:3308/db_name
[...]
```

And then i have define the environnement variable in the config/doctrine.yaml :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      default_connection: default
      connections:
        default:
          dbname:           Symfony
          user:             root
          password:         null
          host:             localhost
          server_version:   '8.0'
          driver: pdo_mysql
          charset: UTF8
```

So i run the following command :

```
> php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

But the 'Symfony' database have been created under mariadb.

:( I don't understand why because i have define precisely that i use a 8.0 version and this version is not a mariadb version.

I've also try this :

```
# .symfony/services.yaml
mydatabase:
    # supported versions: 5.7, 8.0
    type: oracle-mysql:8.0
    disk: 1024
```

As the [symfony documentation saying to do](https://symfony.com/doc/master/cloud/services/mysql.html), but it still not working at all.
I have got the following error message as mydatabase is not a symfony services :

```
C:\Users\vincp\Symfony\charming_tuto>php bin/console doctrine:database:create

In FileLoader.php line 173:

  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "mydatabase" (in "C:\Users\vincp\Symfony\charming_tuto\con
  fig/services.yaml"). Looked for namespace "mydatabase", found ""framework", "sensio_framework_extra", "twig", "twig
  _extra", "web_profiler", "monolog", "debug", "webpack_encore", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "maker"" in C:\Us
  ers\vincp\Symfony\charming_tuto\config/services.yaml (which is being imported from "C:\Users\vincp\Symfony\charming
  _tuto\src\Kernel.php").
```

I wanna use mysql because this is the DBMS that i use usually.
(If you think that i should use mariadb instead of mysql i'm open to that, but give me some arguments. I'd be really interseted in)

Comment: ENV db string looks fine to me, at the doctrine.yaml it seems to much not needed stuff to me, also i dont use the service.yaml

Comment: If it writes the data to your MariaDB instance, then probably the config gets mixed up. You can use `bin/console debug:container --env-vars` to check if your `.env` gets overwritten somehow. You might also want to check `bin/console debug:config doctrine dbal` to double check whether the configuration uses the env vars or some fixed parameters, e.g. the database or server name. In your app you can also use the web profiler to check which db connection is used.

Comment: Ok ! I forgot to set up the port. Thank you @dbrumann the ```bin/console debug:config doctrine dbal ``` help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a server issue. So first, make sure that MySQL is running on your server besides MariaDB (how to do it depends on the type of server you are using).

If yes, it might be a port setting issue: I see that you set the database port to 3308. That is probably the port on which MariaDB is listenning. Try to determine if there is another db running on your server listening to another port (for example 3306 is very often the default MySQL port). To do so, on a Linux server you could try the following command :

```
netstat -tlnp | grep mysql
```

If you find only `x x.x.x.x:3308` address or so, I bet that MySQL is not running on your server and you only run a MariaDB instance. But if you find addresses on other ports (for example `x x.x.x.x:3306`) chances are that a MySQL instance is running and listens that other port. If that's the case, you should consequently change the `DATABASE_URL` in your .env file.